# Why is Eclipse reporting a JUnit compilation error when I can compile and run the test fine in a terminal?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, compilation

I’m using Eclipse Juno with Java 6 on Mac 10.9.5.  I have a Maven (using version 3.2.3) project, “my project” and am trying to compile and run (within Eclipse) a JUnit test that uses a class from another project.  In my JUnit test, I have

```
import org.mainco.subco.test.utils.AbstractNTsubcoTests;
```

which produces the Eclipse compilation error, “The import org.mainco.subco.test.utils.AbstractNTsubcoTests cannot be resolved.”  I have this dependency in “myproject”’s pom.xml file …

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
                <artifactId>other project</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

which includes the class.  Also, in Eclipse, I include the other project that has this class.  In a terminal, I can compile and run this Just test just fine.  I tried running

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in the terminal in my “myproject”’s root directory and refreshing “my project” within Eclipse (even restarted Eclipse).  Yet still, this compilation error remains.  How do I make it go away and get my test to compile and run within Eclipse?

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will not do what you think it will. If you open your `pom.xml` in Eclipse, and go to "Dependency Hierarchy", can you find a file "other project-${project.version}.jar"? Do you have a file `.m2/repository/org/mainco/subco/other project/other project-${project.version}.jar` in your home directory?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes, in as far as this, "otherproject - 78.0.0-SNAPSHOT - tests [test]" appears in my Dependency Hierarchy.  The answer to the second question is also yes.

Comment: So I assume the .jar also appears in the Eclipse project, under "Maven Dependencies"? Open the class file with the problem, and do Source > Organize Imports.

Comment: Yes, teh dependency is there.  I opened the JUnit Java file where the compiation error is happening (you meant .java and not .class, right?) and did Source -> Orgnaization Imports.  A few things got shuffled around but the compilation error remains.

Comment: That would seem like you got the wrong dependency .jar. In Eclipse, can you expand the jar, and see if you can find the class in there?

Comment: When I expand the JAR it doesn't list classes (none of them do), only other JARs.  But above you can see how I declared the dependency in my pom and the unit test runs fine at teh command line.  Is there an Eclipse-specific file I should be checking?

Comment: This sounds like the .jar was incorrectly built? Maven can find it, but it is missing all the .class files. Find the file in `.m2/repository/org/mainco/subco/other project/other project-${project.version}.jar`, make a copy, rename the copy to .zip, open that in your browser and see what is inside. You should be able to find: `org/mainco/subco/test/utils/AbstractNTsubcoTests.class`.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is quite old, but this also happened to me using latest eclipse version in 2020.

In the end, I had to configure the build path of the project, and in the "Source" tab, scroll down to src/test/java folder and change "Contains test resources" from false to true (double click).